# adding a new kubernetes node pool to existing cluster with regular channel as release channel

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to add a new node pool into an existing GKE cluster.  Failing with the below error.

```
Node pool version cannot be set to 1.14.6-gke.1 when releaseChannel REGULAR is set.
```

Any advice on how i can get around this?

**EDIT:**  I finally managed to create a new pool but only after my master was auto-updated.   looks like for auto-updated clusters this is a limitation.  the new node being created seems to default to the version of the master and if the master is on a deprecated version and is pending auto upgrade, all one can do it wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That version was removed from GKE yesterday: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-notes#version_updates

```
The following versions are no longer available for new clusters or upgrades.

    1.13.7-gke.24
    1.13.9-gke.3
    1.13.9-gke.11
    1.13.10-gke.0
    1.13.10-gke.7
    1.14.6-gke.1
    1.14.6-gke.2
    1.14.6-gke.13
```

Comment: So what procedures do i follow to add a new nodepool?  Should i upgrade master first?  I thought I was on auto upgrade.  Need to verify.

Comment: Since I'm on autoupdate, i can't update manually and as per release schedule, my region only updates on day 4.  I suppose i have to wait it out.

Comment: you can add a node pool using a supported version that is earlier that that of your master, such as 1.13.11-gke.5. You can check available versions in your region using `gcloud container get-server-config`

Comment: if cluster is set to auto update.  gke version is not editable when a new node pool is being created.   my cluster went through auto update and i was then able to create my new pool.

Comment: while this did not actually provide me any remediation or workarounds, it did at least help me understand the problem on hand.  hence accepting this as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have enrolled the cluster in a REGULAR release channel and you can not currently disable[1] the release channel to do manual upgrades. You need to wait for the auto upgrade as described in the release notes[2].

To stop using release channels and go back to specifying an exact version, you must recreate the cluster without the --release-channel flag.

[1]-https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/release-channels#changing_and_disabling_release_channels

[2]-https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-notes-regular#october_30_2019

Answer (score 0):

When you're using a release channel the web cloud console does not let you select a version when creating a node pool, but the API/CLI does.

I'm in the same situation as you: the release channel version that my master is on was revoked, but I was able to add a new node pool with a previous version set in terraform.