# How can I downgrade GKE master and exit Rapid channel

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I didn't notice my GKE cluster is in Rapid channel. Until today I want to add Node Pool.

It shows `Node version "1.17.5-gke.6" is unsupported.`

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-notes-rapid#may_27_2020

My questions are:

1. How to downgrade GKE master version
2. How to update a GKE cluster don't use rapid channel

I can't find anything about that in gcloud cli, official documents and stackoverflow.

Comment: Adding as a comment as it's not technically an answer to your question, but you can still add node pools for clusters on revoked release channel versions, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63287231/5769763

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a cluster you have two options to choose from

A. Release channel [Rapid/Regular/Stable]

B. Static version

1.How to downgrade GKE master version.

> From [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/upgrading-a-cluster#about), it mentions that if you are in release channel [Rapid/Regular/Stable], downgrading is not possible.

> With static version it is possible to downgrade with the following [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/upgrading-a-cluster#downgrading_limitations).

2.How to update a GKE cluster to not use rapid channel.

> This is not possible and it will give the following error

```
Migrating off of releaseChannel RAPID is not supported.
```

More information can be also found [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/release-channels#unsubscribing_from_a_release_channel) in regards to the migration between different release channels.

Comment: Thank you. It's a clear answer exactly what I need.